# My pagination didn't work. in my ASP.net MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dttable_itno').dataTable({
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "aaSorting": [],
      "oLanguage": {
          "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
          "sInfo": "_START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_"
        }
    });

  } );
</script>
}
```

this is my script code for pagination.

is their something lacking in this codes?

Comment: You should add the view as well.

Comment: I already add a view, and on that view that script is also there.